# create files as apache:apache

Tags: php, codeigniter, chown

I am using Codeigniter's `file helper` class to `create` and `write` to files. (for logging) Is there a way I can change the `user:group` to `apache:apache` for these files programmatically during creation.

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 surjya goper 188 Oct 31 02:03 mylog.log
```

I tried `php`'s `chown command` just after file creation but it **fails** saying '**not permitted**'. This is because `php` **allows only `if` you are a super user**.

Any work around for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, afaik, codeigniter work under web server, so the user and group is the same that web server right?. Change the user and group of your web server and it will work

Comment: The user and group in my httpd conf file are already apache and apache                                                                ps -ef | grep apache
apache     872   869  0 05:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: What user is the file written as if not apache?

Comment: Mmmm, i think you are creating this file through command line instead of web server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that directly in PHP but you could always call a .sh script on the server to do it for you using shell_exec().

From my understanding, only a su can use chown, so you'd probably need to make an 'expect' script (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35328_01/E35336/html/vmcli-script.html) that will let the script become su, so it can chown the file.

Comment: For the record, I think sal00m is right, and you created this file through the command line. If you generated it from PHP it would be owned by the webserver's user (www-data or apache).